# 404 Error When Using Traefik With Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, traefik

My setup is over Rancher/Docker, and I'm trying to get my InvoiceNinja stack online through the use of Traefik.

I currently have the two other containers that I've been able to make public, but haven't had to try and connect through a nginx container before.

When accessing https://invoiceninja.example.com, I simply get 404 error. I can access it locally just using the IP and port of the host & container just fine.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: invoiceninja/invoiceninja:latest
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    environment:
      APP_ENV: production
      APP_DEBUG: false
      APP_URL: https://${TRAEFIK_HOST}
      APP_CIPHER: AES-256-CBC
      APP_KEY: ${APP_KEY}
      DB_STRICT: false
      DB_HOST: mysql
      DB_DATABASE: ninja_db
      DB_USERNAME: ninja
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_USER_PASS}
      {{- if (.Values.MOBILE_APP_SECRET)}}
      API_SECRET: ${MOBILE_APP_SECRET}
      {{- end}}
      {{- if (.Values.GMAPS_KEY)}}
      GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY: ${GMAPS_KEY}
      {{- end}}
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      {{- if (.Values.HOST_LABEL)}}
      io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: ${HOST_LABEL}
      {{- end}}
      io.rancher.sidekicks: cron, web
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - Logo:/var/www/app/public/logo
      - Storage:/var/www/app/storage
  cron:
    image: invoiceninja/invoiceninja:latest
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c 'bash -s <<EOF
      trap "break;exit" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
      sleep 300s
      while /bin/true; do
        ./artisan ninja:send-invoices
        ./artisan ninja:send-reminders
        sleep 1h
      done
      EOF'
    environment:
      APP_ENV: production
      APP_DEBUG: false
      APP_URL: https://${TRAEFIK_HOST}
      APP_CIPHER: AES-256-CBC
      APP_KEY: ${APP_KEY}
      DB_STRICT: false
      DB_HOST: mysql
      DB_DATABASE: ninja_db
      DB_USERNAME: ninja
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_USER_PASS}
      {{- if .Values.MOBILE_APP_SECRET}}
      API_SECRET: ${MOBILE_APP_SECRET}
      {{- end}}
      {{- if .Values.GMAPS_KEY}}
      GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY: ${GMAPS_KEY}
      {{- end}}
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      {{- if .Values.HOST_LABEL}}
      io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: ${HOST_LABEL}
      {{- end}}
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: on-failure
    volumes_from:
      - app
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ninja_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASS}
      MYSQL_USER: ninja
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_USER_PASS}
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      {{- if .Values.HOST_LABEL}}
      io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: ${HOST_LABEL}
      {{- end}}
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - Database:/var/lib/mysql
  web:
    image: nginx
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      {{- if .Values.HOST_LABEL}}
      io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: ${HOST_LABEL}
      {{- end}}
      {{- if .Values.TRAEFIK_HOST}}
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.frontend.rule: Host:${TRAEFIK_HOST}
      traefik.port: "80"
      traefik.frontend.entryPoints: https
      traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: true
      {{- else}}
      traefik.enable: false
      {{- end}}
    links:
      - app
    networks:
      - public-proxy
    ports:
      - "${WEB_PORT}:80"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /RancherConfig/${DATA_DIR}/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    volumes_from:
      - app
networks:
  public-proxy:
    external: true
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
user www-data;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    upstream backend {
        server app:9000;
    }
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    server {
        listen      80 default;
        server_name invoiceninja.example.com;

        root /var/www/app/public;

        index index.php;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        sendfile off;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass backend;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried (and still have) using the "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: true" label as a similar issue, but does not seem to make a difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed docker-compose.yml that works properly:

```
version: '2'
services:
  invoiceninja:
    image: invoiceninja/invoiceninja:latest
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      {{- if (.Values.HOST_LABEL)}}
      io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: ${HOST_LABEL}
      {{- end}}
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro # Syncronize time of container with the host system
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro # Syncronize timezone of container with the host system
      - /RancherCattle/${DATA_DIR}/Configuration/.env:/var/www/app/.env
      - /RancherCattle/${DATA_DIR}/Logo:/var/www/app/public/logo
      - /RancherCattle/${DATA_DIR}/Storage:/var/www/app/storage
  cron:
    image: invoiceninja/invoiceninja:latest
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c 'bash -s <<EOF
      trap "break;exit" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
      sleep 300s
      while /bin/true; do
        ./artisan ninja:send-invoices
        ./artisan ninja:send-reminders
        sleep 1d
      done
      EOF'
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      {{- if .Values.HOST_LABEL}}
      io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: ${HOST_LABEL}
      {{- end}}
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: on-failure
    volumes_from:
      - invoiceninja
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ninja_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASS}
      MYSQL_USER: ninja_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_USER_PASS}
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      {{- if .Values.HOST_LABEL}}
      io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: ${HOST_LABEL}
      {{- end}}
      traefik.enable: false
    networks:
      - db-admin
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro # Syncronize time of container with the host system
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro # Syncronize timezone of container with the host system
      - /RancherCattle/${DATA_DIR}/Database:/var/lib/mysql
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      {{- if .Values.HOST_LABEL}}
      io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: ${HOST_LABEL}
      {{- end}}
      {{- if .Values.TRAEFIK_HOST}}
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.frontend.rule: Host:${TRAEFIK_HOST}
      traefik.frontend.entryPoints: http,https
      traefik.frontend.headers.forceSTSHeader: true
      traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect: true
      traefik.frontend.headers.STSPreload: true
      traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds: 15552000
      traefik.port: "80"
      {{- else}}
      traefik.enable: false
      {{- end}}
      io.rancher.sidekicks: invoiceninja,cron
    links:
      - invoiceninja
    networks:
      - public-proxy
    ports:
      - "${WEB_PORT}:80"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /RancherCattle/${DATA_DIR}/Configuration/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    volumes_from:
      - invoiceninja

networks:
  db-admin:
    external: true
  public-proxy:
    external: true
```

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    upstream backend {
        server invoiceninja:9000;
    }
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    server {
        listen      80 default;
        server_name _;

        root /var/www/app/public;

        index index.php;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        sendfile off;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass backend;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS 1;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm coming back to this from a while ago, so I may not entirely remember what all of the issues were.

From what I can remember:

- Inconsistent naming of containers, using the wrong hostnames.
- Using environment variables in the docker-compose.yml file caused some issues with not being able to change them later. I often did not completely delete the persistent data volume when removing the containers, so that also caused issues, with environment variables previously set, and they weren't easily changed with a new deployment.